# How to display an array based on Option Select? (reactjs)

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I want to have options where if a user chooses 'all' it should display the whole array, if 'active' then only items in array that are not checked, and 'complete' for all checked values.

But, I don't get the whole array when switching between options. For example, if I choose 'active', then 'complete' and then 'all', at the end nothing will show because after switching array is empty.

I tried to copy existing array in temporary state and then manipulate with it, but not working.

This is how it looks like:

```
const [todo, dispatch] = useReducer((state: any, action: any): any => {
    switch (action.type) {
        //...
        case 'SELECT':
            switch (action.option) {
                case 'all':
                    const temp1 = [...state]
                    return temp1
                case 'complete':
                    const temp2 = [...state]
                    return temp2.filter((i: any) => i.isCheck === true)
                case 'active':
                    const temp3 = [...state]
                    return temp3.filter((i: any) => i.isCheck === false)
                default:
                    return state
            }
    }
}, [])
```

```
<select onChange={(e: any) => dispatch({ type: 'SELECT', option: e.target.value })}>
    <option value="choose" selected>Choose</option>
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="active">Active</option>
    <option value="complete">Complete</option>
</select>
```

And here is whole component : https://pastebin.com/Xr1gm4dV

Any solutions or ideas?

EDIT:

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState([{}])

const [todo, dispatch] = useReducer((state: any, action: any): any => {

    setOptions([...state])

    switch (action.type) {
        //...
        case 'SELECT':
            switch (action.option) {
                case 'all':
                    setOptions([...state])
                    return options
                case 'complete':
                    setOptions([...state])
                    return options.filter((i: any) => i.isCheck === true)
                case 'active':
                    setOptions([...state])
                    return options.filter((i: any) => i.isCheck === false)
                default:
                    return state
            }
    }
})
```

Comment: You are modifying your original array therefore whenever you are filtering array, fitered values are lost forever. Instead try to store 'all', 'active' and 'complete' in your state and filter todo appropriately while rendering.

Comment: Ok, I did something, now only "all" doesn't work like it suppose to. Can you check my EDIT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your original array in another state. Now you can render using todo array. OriginalArray never gets lost.

```js
const [originalArray, setOriginalArray] = useState([])

const [todo, dispatch] = useReducer((state: any, action: any): any => {
    switch (action.type) {
        //...
        case 'SELECT':
            switch (action.option) {
                case 'all':
                    return originalArray
                case 'complete':
                    return originalArray.filter((i: any) => i.isCheck === true)
                case 'active':
                    return originalArray.filter((i: any) => i.isCheck === false)
                default:
                    return state
            }
    }
})
```

Edit (posting working code here)

```js
import React, { useRef, useReducer, useState } from 'react'

export default function App() {

    const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | any>(null)

    const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (inputRef.current?.value !== "") {
            dispatch({
                type: 'ADD_TODO',
                payload: inputRef.current?.value,
                id: editingIndex
            })
        }
        inputRef.current && (inputRef.current.value = "")
    }

    const [editingIndex, setEditingIndex] = useState<null | number>(null)
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState<'all' | 'active' | 'selected'>('all')

    const [todo, dispatch] = useReducer((state: any, action: any): any => {
        
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'ADD_TODO':
                setEditingIndex(null)
                const tempState = [...state]
                if (action.id) {
                    tempState[action.id] = { ...tempState[action.id], name: action.payload }
                }
                else {
                    tempState.push({
                        id: action.id | state.length,
                        name: action.payload,
                        isCheck: false,
                        toggleAll: false
                    })
                }
                return tempState
            case 'CHECK_TODO':
                return state.filter((item: any, index: any): any => {
                    if (index === action.id) {
                        item.isCheck = !item.isCheck
                    }
                    return item
                })
            case 'EDIT_TODO':
                inputRef.current.focus()
                inputRef.current.value = action.payload
                return state
            case 'DELETE_TODO':
                return state.filter((item: any, index: any) => index !== action.id)
            case 'CLEAR_TODOS':
                return []
            case 'ON_OFF':
                const newState = state.map((item: any) => {
                    item.toggleAll = !item.toggleAll
                    return item
                })
                return newState.map((item: any) => {
                    item.isCheck = item.toggleAll
                    return item
                })
            default: 
                return state 
        }
    }, [])

    const handleEditing = (index: number, item: { name: string }) => {
        setEditingIndex(index);
        dispatch({
            type: 'EDIT_TODO',
            id: index,
            payload: item.name
        })
    }

    const todos = todo.map((item: any, index: number) => {
        if(selected === 'active' && item.isCheck) return null
        if(selected === 'complete' && !item.isCheck) return null
        return (
            <li key={index}>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={item.isCheck}
                    onChange={() => dispatch({ type: 'CHECK_TODO', id: index })}
                />
                {item.name}
                <button onClick={() => handleEditing(index, item)}>/</button>
                <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_TODO', id: index })}>x</button>
            </li>
        )
    })

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder='Buy milk'
                    ref={inputRef}
                />
            </form>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'CLEAR_TODOS' })}>Clear</button>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'ON_OFF' })}>On/Off</button>

            <select value={selected} onChange={(e: any) => setSelected(e.target.value)}>
                <option value="choose" selected>Choose</option>
                <option value="all">All</option>
                <option value="active">Active</option>
                <option value="complete">Complete</option>
            </select>
            <ul>{todos}</ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Aha, I did something like that, can you see my EDIT? I tried that and only option 'all' doesn't work like it suppose to, why is that so? EDIT: And I modified code like you did, still not working like it suppose to

Comment: I saw your code. You are still modifying originalArray. Can you please host a sandbox. That will be easier to work with.

Comment: Did you mean this? https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-s43lh?file=/App.tsx

Comment: Try this https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-yjcqi?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I'm sorry, I additionally added package.json in there, it is displaying everything now, can you check it again? I open what you did but still same problem.

Comment: Welcome @Aniram, Happy to help. Please mark it solved.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was fine, but I noticed the same problem after adding package.json in your code, can you check it again? Now it is displaying everything so you can see and test it. The file is added, it is on my link again

Comment: hej @gautamits, can you check my link again and test your code there? And I don't see any difference in your code with mine

Comment: @aniram did you see my code. I didnt use original Array. useReducer was only adding, deleting, checking unchecking. I used another state to store selection type (all / completed/ active) and returned null from todos appropriately.

Comment: I did, everything seems the same as mine, can you open my link again ( https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-s43lh?file=/App.tsx ), there is package.json added so everything is displayed now, you can copy that code of yours and test it again please?

Comment: @Aniram, I have updated code in snippet. Please see that I have removed 'SELECT' action from reducer. I am also returning null from todos function for some conditions.

Comment: I see it now, copy-pasted and got with 1 error: `if(selected === 'complete' && !item.isCheck) return null` : _"This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"all" | "active" | "selected"' and '"complete"' have no overlap"_

Comment: That is just typescript. remove *const [selected, setSelected] = useState<'all' | 'active' | 'selected'>('all')* with *const [selected, setSelected] = useState('all')*

Comment: I removed it and it is working now :) thank you again!

Comment: Welcome @Aniram. Anytime.